# Creating an overlay in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have div that I display dynamically when certain conditions arise.

When I display the div, how can I create the effect of the background dimming and my div appearing to be prominent? much like a number of AJAX lightboxes or popups. (Thickbox, ColorBox, PrettyPhoto, etc)

I don;t quite get how they do it. I have everything else working in my own custom code except that piece.

Can anyone help me learn how?

Comment: are you looking for something similar to "dim the lights" function on a number of websites? Where the page content dims out and the video/div stays bright? Well how thats done is by placing an invisible layer 100% width and height below the selected div but above the rest of the page content. That layer has a background of black and the opacity is changed to fade in.

Comment: Searching for dim the lights jquery this is one link I found: http://www.ajaxupdates.com/lights-out-dimming-covering-background-content-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a div over the content and set an opacity. I use this in one of my sites.

```
<div id="error_wrapper">
    <div id="site_error">
        Error:
    </div>
</div>

div#error_wrapper {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);

}

div#site_error {
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Or `rgba()` for modern browsers.

Comment: very nice. Makes sense. I thought it had something to do with opacity! I was able to adapt this to what I wanted. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you know how to round corners on a div? I can find examples, but they all involve using images. Is there a pure CSS way?

Comment: Not in css2. Perhaps css3 offers some options to round div cornors. You better start a new question about the subject on SO since it is not directly related to this one. I also see you have a lot of open questions without an accepted answer. Please accept answers if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a layer that is the full width & height of your page and give it a higher z index than your whole page, you can create this effect. Then put your appearing div over it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use global div of the size of the page to cover any other content:

http://jsfiddle.net/CHkNd/1/

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but this way you can still use the content on the site below the current window. So if you scroll down than some content is still visible. Better to use position fixed I think.

Comment: @Mark You may be right, I don't have access to my actual code right now.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that you can play around with.

http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/1/

Hope this helps.

Bob